# How do i get a shannon and simpson diversity index using raw count table and metadata (vegan package)

Tags: r, vegan

I'm a beginner and i have a question regarding Shannon and Simpson index. I have a raw count table that looks like this

[image: raw_count_table]

```
    Datasets    R21P2_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R22P1_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R22P4_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R22P6_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R23P4_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R23P5_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R22P2_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond    R22P3_BS_non_rRNA_diamond
Candidatus Koribacter   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Candidatus Koribacter versatilis    6450.7397   3675.8171   2588.1077   2657.2302   2345.8489   0   6476.0293   6215.4624
Candidatus Sulfotelmatomonas    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Candidatus Sulfotelmatomonas gaucii 0   0   0   0   0   2988    0   0
Edaphobacter    2452.491    2315.793    0   0   2334.1106   955 3006.5918   2504.095
Edaphobacter modestus   0   0   0   0   0   2791    0   0
Occallatibacter 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Occallatibacter savannae    3342.1418   0   0   0   0   0   2275.6936   0
unclassified Acidobacteriales   713.793 1381.9713   371.48083   372.63043   413.5484    0   1512.612    1004.95465
Acidobacteriales bacterium  1989.0435   2009.239    2346.533    2188.6824   2098.4421   0   2224.878    2977.275
Bryobacterales  92.96951    63.00996    77.73442    82.42516    65.914925   47  74.10613    63.01696
Bryobacteraceae 632.5847    539.4786    575.83264   574.2777    421.6749    344 999.37415   679.9198
Paludibaculum   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Paludibaculum fermentans    5697.7427   3003.9468   3720.4888   3304.1206   2315.1487   2032    4642.855    4024.7937
Solibacteraceae 43.124413   14.159542   25.562664   24.5313 26.185379   26  37.688263   28.744577
```

and a metadata file:

```
id,day,yield
R21P2_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,0,1
R22P1_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,30,1
R22P4_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,30,0
R22P6_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,30,0
R23P4_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,60,0
R23P5_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,60,0
R22P2_BS_sortme_non_rRNA_diamond,30,1
R22P3_BS_non_rRNA_diamond,30,1
```

I would like to get both shannon and simpson diversity and then plot them by 'yield' and 'day', so it looks like this

[image: shannon index by yield]

[image: shannon index by day]

How do i go about it using vegan package? especially getting the both shannon and simpson index out. Help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I tried transposing my data and now it looks like this:

```
"Level_1"   "Day"   "Yield" "Acidobacteria" "candidate division NC10"   "candidate division WOR-3"  "Candidatus Aminicenantes"  "Candidatus Eisenbacteria"  "Candidatus Rokubacteria"   "Calditrichaeota"   "Elusimicrobia" "Bacteroidetes" "Ignavibacteriae"   "candidate division Zixibacteria"   "Candidatus Latescibacteria"    "Gemmatimonadetes"  "Nitrospirae"   "Proteobacteria"    "Candidatus Abyssubacteria" "Candidatus Omnitrophica"   "Lentisphaerae" "Planctomycetes"    "Verrucomicrobia"   "Spirochaetes"  "Actinobacteria"    "Armatimonadetes"   "Chloroflexi"   "Cyanobacteria" "Deinococcus-Thermus"   "Firmicutes"
"R11P4_BS_diamond"  0   "Low"   22225.703   574.2619    0   140.88957   2322.9353   0   1029.0415   19.166956   3195.5298   256.63806   0.995686    0   1352.266    3617.2026   29759.188   0   28.37705    102.057816  4175.409    3554.35 1059.6588   5686.363    666.98517   35559.43    4108.5737   6.845341    2762.282
"R13P1_BS_diamond"  60  "High"  34864.668   296.10495   0   96.91555    970.3203    0   1011.2066   21.433247   3125.6428   382.53687   0.5824252   0   740.0294    8325.418    26701.049   0   43.33243    95.63422    2905.2532   5159.7046   1287.509    5290.517    720.45996   36515.844   3476.9617   7.105587    3380.0461
"R13P3_BS_diamond"  60  "High"  30511.857   201.64407   1252.1503   160.40663   1576.6329   0   0   20.618717   3181.9224   527.6994    0.17473489  0   618.5615    5305.126    27084.434   0   72.86445    81.251724   3752.0823   4092.466    2143.2983   6419.4106   869.3061    35032.426   3004.916    5.5915165   2518.454
"R13P6_BS_diamond"  60  "Low"   23491.105   201.67783   0   115.17029   2832.317    0   0   20.043161   2692.534    1185.2467   0   0   2077.0115   1735.1355   38256.37    0   1011.81616  99.385  4316.4453   4472.325    917.51984   9140.408    1159.6995   21273.375   3704.8694   7.061839    2208.4863
"R14P1_BS_diamond"  90  "High"  21952.639   196.00256   0   37.935978   1538.1635   0   0   0   3867.7136   1045.1714   0   0   924.8651    1710.6316   32768.605   0   0   0   3437.2456   2696.6157   1705.3628   14147.135   1296.3215   33106.695   3081.4202   11.24029    2023.2522
"R14P3_BS_diamond"  90  "High"  23845.86    189.5785    0   121.52756   1219.4237   0   0   19.843521   3474.5222   285.2086    0.3363309   0   1093.2996   4346.6284   32942.938   0   37.66906    97.19962    3969.1528   4942.8306   761.90155   9911.335    933.76666   34448.355   3229.0007   7.6235  2885.943

veganData  <- read.csv("./transposed-bs-allseason-230922-taxonomy-phylum.csv", header= TRUE,sep ='\t')

diversity(veganData[, -(1:4)],"simpson",MARGIN = 2)
```

output obtained:
candidate.division.NC10        candidate.division.WOR.3
0.9525816                       0.8715260
Candidatus.Aminicenantes        Candidatus.Eisenbacteria
0.9551888                       0.9532059
Candidatus.Rokubacteria                 Calditrichaeota
1.0000000                       0.4999618
Elusimicrobia                   Bacteroidetes
0.9380819                       0.9570427
Ignavibacteriae candidate.division.Zixibacteria
0.9466634                       0.7953193

Comment: The values in your table do not look like counts since they have decimals. If they are not counts, shannon and simpson values may not be valid. The `vegan` package includes a very useful document called [Vegan: ecological diversity](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/diversity-vegan.pdf) that provides examples on how to compute diversity indices.

Comment: @dcarlson is correct in saying that diversities may not be valid for non-count data. However, that does not stop **vegan** (or most scientists) to calculate diversities. `vegan::diversity` will calculate diversities for each observation of your data. Your data are transposed to **vegan** standard: either transpose (`t()`) or set `MARGIN=2` in `diversity`. You get values for each obsevations, then you can use this result vector in other functions, such as boxplots.

Comment: hi @dcarlson, thank you for the response. I generated this abundance output from a tool called Megan6 which places reads into the taxonomy by assigning each read to a taxon at some level in the NCBI hierarchy, based on their hits to known sequences. Its sad that i cannot calculate diversity index using this. What do you think of the idea of transforming the decimals into int by rounding them of?

Comment: @JariOksanen thank you so much for the response. I tried transposing my data and i have posted the output above. Im pretty confused about MARGIN=1 or 2. What is the difference? Also is there a way to obtain diversity by grouping the variables? for instance, diversity for Yield- 'Low' and "High"